# Add clr reference to WordPerfect dll using python

Tags: .net, ironpython

After trying several variations on the theme of clr.AddReference, I am still unable to add a reference to the "wpwin14.dll", which is the interop reference for WordPerfect X4.  I am using Eclipse on Windows, and other clr calls work fine, so I assume my IronPython/IDE setup is fine.  I have successfully added that file name to Visual Studio for a project in VB.NET, so I believe that file is the correct file to use.

The simple code I am using is this:

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFile("wpwin14.dll")
```

I have also tried clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath using the full path on my machine.
I have also tried these commands from the IronPython command line.

Just in case the wpwin14.dll file was not appropriate for the .NET reference, I converted the associated wpwin14.tlb file into a dll, using the tlbimp command.  That did not work either.

The error message I get is this:
IOError: System.IO.IOException: Could not add reference to assembly wpwin14.dll

Am I missing something basic here?

Comment: Is `wpwin14.dll` a .NET or COM assembly?  You can't just use _any_ dll here.

Comment: Oh...it is definitely a COM assembly.  I guess I need to take a different route.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to interact with the COM library would be to use something like the following

```
from System import Activator, Type
shell = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID('Shell.Application'))
```

Just replace Shell.Application with the ProgID for the WordPerfect application COM object. IronPython will take care of the method resolution when you start calling methods.